# How to Stream Video to "Kinesis Video Stream" from phone camera accessed on browser using Javascript

Tags: amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-js, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

**Use case:** Multiple users login into the web portal to stream video over a web browser using their phone camera. The phone Camera (Producer) is accessed using HTML5/Javascript, which streams the video to KVS (Kinesis Video Stream), there are multiple consumers like EC2 to process the stream and record findings into Kinesis Topic & another consumer writing into S3.

I could not find any documentation on how to stream video from a mobile browser using phone camera into a Kinesis Video Stream.